# GRUB does not load, only shows a blinking cursor

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation

I may mix things up here because I don't know extensively about a computer's architecture.

So I bought an ASUS EEE PC 1025E and wanted to replace Windows 7 Starter by a GNU/Linux distribution, so I chose Debian. However I wanted something else so I put Ubuntu 13.10 on an USB stick and started the installation from the stick.

Here's where I did something really dumb. While navigating through the installation menus I noticed the computer was getting slow (it didn't surprise me because c'mon, it's a tiny computer), so I shut down the computer. What I didn't notice was that although it didn't seem like it, Ubuntu was actually being installed while I was in the menus (The program didn't tell me it). Since I ordered Ubuntu to write itself over all of my HDD, I ended with a messed up hard drive because I interrupted the installation process.

Symptoms:
When I boot up the computer, the ASUS screen shows for a second, then a blinking cursor appears which I assume is from GRUB. From here it seems I can't do anything except press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> which restarts my computer and does the same process.

Here's the tricky part: due to my computer being a netbook it doesn't have anything to read disks, so any solution involving a disk doesn't work.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated because I basically put my computer out of service at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your usb to reinstall. You are not going to salvage the interrupted installation.

Comment: How can it be done? My computer doesn't seem to react to my USB.

Comment: You can boot the usb with your EEE 1025. Plug in your usb, turn it on and hit the Esc key (not F2). This opens boot menu and with it - a chance to boot/install from CD or usb.

Comment: I'll test it out when I'll have the computer with me again. Thank you!